# C: why printing a null char with %s prints "(null)"?

Tags: c, gcc

Why does printing a null char ('\0', 0) with %s prints the "(null)" string actually?

Like this code:

```
char null_byte = '\0';
printf("null_byte: %s\n", null_byte);
```

...printing:

```
null_byte: (null)
```

...and it even runs without errors under Valgrind, all I get is the compiler warning `warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]` (note: I'm using gcc 4.6.3 on 32bit Ubuntu)

Comment: `"%s"` expects `char *` or `char[...]` the OP passes `char`.

Comment: I suspect that on 64bit valgrind would proclaim reading invalid bytes, as an 8bytes sized pointer would be grabbed from the stack, whereas only 4 (`sizeof(int)`) had been passed in. On 32bit `sizeof(char*)` is equal `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @alk: Quite possible, on LP64. The OP passes a `char` but this is promoted to `int`.

Comment: So, do you observer this on a 32 or 64bit OS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's undefined behavior, but it happens that on your implementation:

- the `int` value of 0 that you pass is read by `%s` as a null pointer
- the handling of `%s` by `printf` has special-case code to identify a null pointer and print `(null)`.

Neither of those is required by the standard. The part that is required[*], is that a `char` used in varargs is passed as an `int`.

[*] Well, it's required given that on your implementation all values of `char` can be represented as `int`. If you were on some funny implementation where `char` is unsigned and the same width as `int`, it would be passed as `unsigned int`. I think that funny implementation would conform to the standard.

Comment: nice to know that it actually comes from printing a null pointer via %s ...didn't knew about varargs weirdness though, I'll look deeper into it sometime

Answer (score 4):

Well, for starters, you're doing it wrong. `'\0'` is a character and should be printed with `%c` and not `%s`. I don't know if this is intentional for experimentation purposes.

The actual binary value of `\0` is, well, 0. You're trying to cast the value 0 to a `char *` pointer, which would result in an invalid reference and crash. Your compiler is preventing that with a special treatment of the `%s` value.

Valgrind won't catch it because it runs on the resulting binary, not the source code (you'd need a static analyzer instead). Since the compiler has already converted that call into a safe "null pointer" text, valgrind won't see anything amiss.

Comment: s/compiler/standard library/

Comment: @Potatoswatter not really - isn't it undefined behavior to try to dereference a null pointer? The compiler is then free to "intercept" that in any way...

Comment: ok, that explains a lot, though it's not very helpful what the compiler does for me - it actually prevents me from catching an error with Valgrind. and yes, what I was doing was trying to break a program on purpose and see what kind of error messages Valgrind gives, and here, to my surprise, it didn't find any errors

Comment: if I could mark 2 answers I'd choose yours too for the reasoning behind why Valgrind didn't catch this

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Unless the compiler has an internal implementation of printf, which I doubt, it's just passing the value to the printf function. It's not being cast to (char *) since the compiler doesn't know it's supposed to be a char * (well, it does, so it can print a warning, but it's not allowed to act on that knowledge other than the warning). It's being promoted to an int, since that's what varargs is supposed to do. The compiler hasn't converted anything to any "safe 'null pointer' text".

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi The null pointer happens at runtime. The compiler has already finished its work by that time. The standard library, which is usually a pre-compiled file, contains code implementing `printf`. But the requirements regarding UB on the standard library are similar to the compiler. So your statement is correct if you simply replace "compiler" with "standard library".

Comment: @Potatoswatter I assumed the replacement was a compile-time optimization. Without seeing the assembly, I honestly be able to say if this string is compile-time or run-time.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi No, the compiler doesn't replace literal constant zeroes with a helpful string before passing to `printf` when the corresponding formatter is `%s`. That would be pointless.

Answer (score 1):

null_byte contains 0. When you use %s in printf, you are trying to print a string, which is an adress of a char (a char *). What you do in your code, is that you are passing the adress 0 (NULL) as the adress of your string, which is why the output is null.
The compiler warned you that you passed the wrong type to the %s modifier. try printf("null_byte: %s\n", &null_byte);

Answer (score 0):

Your `printf` statement is trying to print a string and is therefore interprets the value `null_bye` as a `char *` that has the value null. Take heed of the warning. Either do this

```
printf("null_byte: %s\n", &null_byte);
```

or this

```
printf("null_byte: %c\n", null_byte);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `printf` is variadic, the usual argument promotions are performed on `null_byte` so it gets promoted (cast) to `int`, value `0`.

`printf` then reads a `char *` pointer, and the `0` int is interpreted as a null pointer.  Your C standard library has a feature that null strings are printed as `(null)`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an implementation example to other answers, in XV6, which is an educational re-implementation of Unix v6, if you pass a zero value to `%s`, it prints `(null)`:

```
void printf(int fd, const char *fmt, ...) {
    uint *ap = (uint*)(void*)&fmt + 1;
    ...
    if(state == '%') {
        ...
        if(c == 's') {
            s = (char*)*ap;
            ap++;
            if(s == 0)
                s = "(null)";
            while(*s != 0){
                putc(fd, *s);
                s++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```